# After CSS styling a button, the text is not showing up

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to learn some HTML and CSS for fun and made what I think a pretty cool button for my "enter page" but after adding the last effects the text does not show up. after removing the "border-left,right,top" the text shows but the box loses the full effect. I currently have the button set up to display in the center of the screen while I have a background image that takes the full page up. The colors are meant to be similar to work with the background image and i have checked they shouldn't blend into each other

CSS Code

```
input.Button {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  background: #000000;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.3;
  font-size: 400%;
  color: snow;
  font-family: "Impact", Charcoal, serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid slategray;
}
```

Edit: HTML Code

```
<body>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="landingpage.jpg">
    <div class="button">
     <form>
       <input class="Button" type="button" value="Enter" onclick="window.location.href='about.html'" />
     </form>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
input.Button {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  background: #000000;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.3;
  font-size: 400%;
  color: snow;
  font-family: "Impact", Charcoal, serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid slategray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="landingpage.jpg">
    <div class="button">
      <form>
        <input class="Button" type="button" value="Enter" onclick="window.location.href='about.html'" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: “The text does not show up” background and text (color) seem to the same color, is that intended?

Comment: can you provide the html please?

Comment: @stealththeninja s/he has color: show after color: #000

Answer (score 1):

Your border at the top is the same size as the height of your button, so the text basically gets pushed off of it. Try setting a border-top of 50px and you'll see it reappear.

You can play around with it here:
http://www.cssdesk.com/zPURs

Comment: Ahhhhh I see, thank you! The text did raise but so did the background effect of the box.. Is there a way to layer the text on top of it so it keeps the effect?

Comment: I don't think that would be possible. You'd be better off using a background-image. I've created another example. It obviously uses a different background than what you want to achieve but you could easily create an image based on whatever style you want. I suspect you were having problems with centring the button  with absolute sizes so I added a way to do that in the example as well: http://www.cssdesk.com/FKTrE

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you for that! I love being able to see the different ways you can achieve the same result :D but there wouldn't be any way to do it? This is what i have but just need the text just so you have a visual https://gyazo.com/d84f79757d8771f1487d46dbd1e858e3

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the best way to implement this, but you can wrap your button with 2 divs. The first div will be in charge of the positioning in the page. The second div will only have `position: relative` so you can position your button with `absolute` and it  will be calculate based on the wrapper position and not the body.

Then position the button with top: -90px which will hover above your styled div.

```css
input.Button {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 400%;
  color: snow;
  font-family: "Impact", Charcoal, serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: -90px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px;
}

.wrapper{
  background: #000000;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid slategray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button-container{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="landingpage.jpg">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="button-container">
        <form>
          <input class="Button" type="button" value="Enter" onclick="window.location.href='about.html'" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @user7887481 did it help you?